# Reshape numpy array with minimum rate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, rate

I have an array that is not monotonic increasing. I would like to make it monotonic increasing applying a constant rate when the array decreases.

I have create a small example here where the rate is 0.2:

```
# Rate
rate = 0.2

# Array to interpolate
arr1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,2.5,3.5,5.2,7,10,9.5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,11.2, 11.4, 12,10,9,9.5,10.2,10.5,10.8,12,12.5,15],dtype=float)

# Line with constant rate at first monotonic decrease (index 6)
xx1 = 6
xr1 = np.array(np.arange(0,arr1.shape[0]+1),dtype=float)
yr1 = rate*xr1 + (arr1[xx1]-rate*xx1)

# Line with constant rate at second monotonic decrease [index 14]
xx2 = 13
xr2 = np.array(np.arange(0,arr1.shape[0]+1),dtype=float)
yr2 = rate*xr2 + (arr1[xx2]-rate*xx2)

# Line with constant rate at second monotonic decrease [index 14]
xx3 = 20
xr3 = np.array(np.arange(0,arr1.shape[0]+1),dtype=float)
yr3 = rate*xr3 + (arr1[xx3]-rate*xx3)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(arr1,'.-',label='Original')
plt.plot(xr1,yr1,label='Const Rate line 1')
plt.plot(xr2,yr2,label='Const Rate line 2')
plt.plot(xr3,yr3,label='Const Rate line 2')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

The "Original" array is my dataset.
The final results I would like is the blue + red-dashed line. In the figure I highlighted also the "constant rate curves".

[image]

Since I have very large arrays (millions of records), I would like to avoid for-loops over the entire array.

Thanks a lot to everybody for the help!

Comment: Shift a copy of the array by one sample and subtract that from the original to find where one sample is less than the next.

Comment: You should change "reshape" to "interpolate", as "reshaping" is something **entirely unrelated** to this.

Comment: What if rate = 0.3? Then `arr2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4.3, 4.6, 4.9, 5.2, 5, ...])`. As you can see it is not monotonically increasing. So you need to check this... Why not just skip the unwanted points and connect the successive increasing points with a line, e.g. `arr1[6] = 4` with `arr1[11] = 5`, `arr1[13] = 10` with `arr1[18] = 11.2`?

Comment: @AndyK I con connect the points as you suggest, but I need to find the a connecting point is above a line starting from the first point and with a constant rate (I'll update the question to be clearer).

Comment: Why would your expected output to interpolate between `x[20]` and `x[29]`, when `x[26] = x[20]` and `x[27] > x[20]`? Do you expect `x[n] > x[n-1] + 0.2`?

Comment: @NilsWerner, because whenever the original curve decreases I need to have a increasing trend. The minimum amount of "increasing" is given by the red line; as soon as the blue one becomes higher than the red one, I keep the blue (and this is why the final red dashed line is the result I would like to have)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different option: If you are interested in plotting monotonically increasing curve from your data, then you can simply skip the unwanted points between two successive increasing points, e.g. between `arr1[6] = 4` and `arr1[11] = 5`, by connecting them with a line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,2.5,3.5,5.2,7,10,9.5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,11.2, 11.4, 12,10,9,9.5,10.2,10.5,10.8,12,12.5,15],dtype=float)

mask = (arr1 == np.maximum.accumulate(np.nan_to_num(arr1)))

x = np.arange(len(arr1))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, arr1,'.-',label='Original')
plt.plot(x[mask], arr1[mask], 'r-', label='Interp.')    
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
arr2 = arr1[1:] - arr1[:-1]
ind = numpy.where(arr2 < 0)[0]
for i in ind:
    arr1[i] = arr1[i - 1] + rate
```

You may need to replace first any numpy.nan with values, such as numpy.amin(arr1)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to avoid for-loops over the entire array.

Frankly speaking, it is hard to achieve no for-loops in numpy, because numpy as the C-made-library uses for-loops implemented in C / C++. And all sorting algorithm (like np.argwhere, np.all, etc.) requires comparisons and therefore also iterations.

Contrarily, I suggest using at least one explicit loop made in Python (iteration is made only once):

```
arr0 = np.zeros_like(arr1)
num = 1
rate = .2
while(num < len(arr1)):
    if arr1[num] < arr1[num-1] or np.isnan(arr1[num]):
        start = arr1[num-1]
        while(start > arr1[num] or np.isnan(arr1[num])):
            print(arr1[num])
            arr0[num] = arr0[num-1] + rate
            num+=1
        continue
    arr0[num] = arr1[num]
    num +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be expressed in one simple recursive difference equation:

```
y[n] = max(y[n-1] + 0.2, x[n])
```

So the direct Python form would be

```
def func(a):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    out[0] = a[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        out[i] = max(out[i-1] + 0.2, a[i])

    return out
```

Unfortunately, this equation is recursive and non-linear, so finding a vectorized algorithm may be difficult.

However, using Numba we can speed up this loop-based algorithm by a factor of 300:

```
fastfunc = numba.jit(func)

arr1 = np.random.rand(1000000)

%timeit func(arr1)
# 599 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit fastfunc(arr1)
# 2.22 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I think OP wants `10.0, 10.2, 10.4, 10.6, 10.8, 11.2`, not `10.  , 10.24, 10.48, 10.72, 10.96, 11.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do what I wanted with a while loop.

```
# data['myvar'] is the original dataset I want to reshape
data['myvar_corrected'] = data['myvar'].values
temp_d = data['myvar'].fillna(0).values*1.0
dtc = np.maximum.accumulate(temp_d)
data.loc[temp_d < np.maximum.accumulate(dtc),'myvar_corrected'] = float('nan')
stay_in_while = True
min_rate = 5/200000/(24*60)
idx_next = 0
while stay_in_while:
    df_temp = data.iloc[idx_next:]
    if df_tem['myvar'].isnull().sum()>0:
        idx_first_nan = df_temp.reset_index().['myvar_corrected'].isnull().argmax()

        idx_nan_or = (data_new.index.values==df_temp.index.values[idx_first_nan]).argmax()

        x = np.arange(idx_first_nan-1,df_temp.shape[0])
        y0 = df_temp.iloc[idx_first_nan-1]['myvar_corrected']
        rate_curve = min_rate*x + (y0 - min_rate*(idx_first_nan-1))

        damage_m_rate = df_temp.iloc[idx_first_nan-1:]['myvar_corrected']-rate_curve

        try:
            idx_intercept = (data_new.index.values==damage_m_rate[damage_m_rate>0].index.values[0]).argmax()
            data_new.iloc[idx_nan_or:idx_intercept]['myvar'] = rate_curve[0:(damage_m_rate.index.values==damage_m_rate[damage_m_rate>0].index.values[0]).argmax()-1]
            idx_next = idx_intercept + 1
        except:
            stay_in_while = False
    else:
        stay_in_while = False
# Finally I have my result stored in data_new['myvar']
```

In the following picture the result.

[image]

Thanks to everybody for the contribution!